# Avoid globals OR use dependency injection?

Tags: oop, dependency-injection, global

For every instance you are going to use you have to have a `new` somewhere.

- If you have it in the global scope, you are a bad boy.
- If you put it in a class, you did not inject it. Bad boy.

How to be a good boy?

Comment: With a [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)!

Comment: @qujck This is a nice article. I think what is missing from it--but might be in Seemann's book--is an explanation of the OO principle behind the approach--that is, in addition to knowledge (state) and behaviour (method) responsibilities, classes have creation responsibilities, which are for instantiating objects and the associations between them.